# Partial Refresh In ASP page

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a web page developed in ASP. It has 3 regions. One has two combo boxes and date and time of a win CE device. This region has to be refreshed automatically in every 5 seconds.The ASP page is hosted in the WIn CE device.

The requirement are

a. If a system error occurs (for Eg: Error Code 5) during page load or auto refresh, hide the region having combo boxes and date and time fields
b. If an application error occurs (for Eg: Error Code 10) during page load or auto refresh, fill data in the combo or the fields till an error occurs and leave the remaining fields blank

what techniques can I use to fulfill these requirements?
Where can I locate more information on this?

Comment: ASP runs on the server.  You will need to use javascript on the clientside to handle refreshes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ASP runs on the server. You will need to use javascript on the clientside to handle refreshes. – *Dee Jul 7 at 16:31*

That looks like the best answer, thought it is in a comment. You'll have to use AJAX to make what you want work. In Visual Studio, add an UpdatePanel which contains the controls to refresh.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <%-- Region to update --%>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I'm not too used to this so I can really help you more. Maybe check for Asynchronous Post-Back and UpdatePanel Triggers.